# Weird characters in Jenkins Job Configuration

Tags: jenkins

What are these weird characters? Anyone has faced this? How can these be deleted?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remember that Jenkins is just a web app, so presumably the version you're on has some additional `<` in the markup for that particular form. Unless it's causing a problem, I'd just ignore it.

Comment: thank you. It is not causing any problem, is just anyoing. How can I edit that form? I am using version 2.89.1 in two machines, but this "<<" are only dispalyed in the master, the slave interface is ok!

Comment: Very strange indeed! In any case, you may have to put up with the annoyance for now.